# Count number of relationships in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have 2 nodes **Post** and **User**, where user can like the post, which will create a relationship `(user:User)-[:LIKES]->(post)`. I have a problem to calculate number of likes per post. If nobody liked it should return 0, however it always returns 0.
(FYI: I am also calculating who created the post)

Here's my query:

```
MATCH (post:Post)
MATCH (user:User)-[:CREATED]->(post)
OPTIONAL MATCH (post)<-[likes:LIKES]-(:User)
WHERE post.uuid = {postUUID} AND NOT exists(post.deleted)
RETURN post,
       user.username AS `createdBy`,
       count(likes) AS `likes`
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: You have postUUID as a parameter. Do you only want to return data for just the post with that uuid? Because right now your query is getting all posts for all users, and only only getting the likes count for the post with the given UUID (all others will return 0 likes since the OPTIONAL MATCH is only affecting the post with the given uuid)

Comment: Exactly, just need to calculate number of likes of specific post with some uuid. Because when I use just MATCH, it will calculate number of likes, but if there are no likes, the post is not showing in the result.

Comment: And if post.deleted is true, should it still return data, but with likes as 0?

Comment: Nope, if post is deleted, it shows no data. At least not post node. But it should be ok, I've tried also without this check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work better for you:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:CREATED]->(post:Post)
WHERE post.uuid = {postUUID} AND (NOT user.deleted OR NOT EXISTS(user.deleted))
RETURN
  post,
  user.username AS `createdBy`,
  SIZE((post)<-[:LIKES]-(:User)) AS `likes`
```

This query avoids the issue mentioned by @InverseFalcon by only matching `Post` node(s) with the specified uuid.

Also, this query will match `User` nodes that *do* have the `deleted` property, but with a `false` value. Your original query's `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause (which is not necessary) would only match users that did not have the `deleted` property at all.

Comment: Looks like this query always send me that post has 1 like, I checked if there were no likes, then created 2 likes and query still result in 1. I checked it with query: MATCH ()-[likes:LIKES]-() RETURN likes, which shows me 2 User nodes directing at Post with LIKES relationship.

Comment: COUNT() typically isn't applied to a pattern, I'm not quite sure what it's returning. Use SIZE() instead, which will return the number pattern matches.

Comment: You're great. SIZE() works! You should answer this question and I will accept your answer, so other people can see it later.

Comment: OK, see my corrected answer. The `(post)<-[:LIKES]-(:User)` pattern actually returns a collection of paths, so we need to use the `SIZE()` function to get the size of that collection. [I see that @InversFalcon commented as well...).]